# WordPress Return 404 for some image files

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have a domain xyz.com and it is running on wordpress.
I have recently moved from hostgator cpanel hosting to godaddy cpanel hosting.

After migration, the website is running fine but only a few images are returning 404.

I have an image named `ASSEMBLY2.jpg`

under `www.xyz.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ASSEMBLY2.jpg`

When I open the image in the browser, it returns 404 but when I open it in FileZilla or cPanel, I can get the image and view it. It looks strange to me, anyone has any idea?

Comment: file is not therein upload

Comment: please share url of website

Comment: The file is there, I have already mentioned in the question, I can access the file in specified location from FileZilla and cpanel.

Comment: i can't help you without checking website.Sorry for that. :(

Comment: images may be blocked from server side( only open access from some domains )